# Trigger an event in a running process

Tags: c#, communication

I have a process that runs continuesly. I want to trigger that process every once in a while to perform an poeration. The triggering would be done by another process.

I know I can use WCF, but I am looking for a an easier solution, maybe a named Semaphore?

Any ideas?

Best,

Asher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A named [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) will work...

> Named system mutexes are visible
>   throughout the operating system, and
>   can be used to synchronize the
>   activities of processes. You can
>   create a Mutex object that represents
>   a named system mutex by using a
>   constructor that accepts a name. The
>   operating-system object can be created
>   at the same time, or it can exist
>   before the creation of the Mutex
>   object. You can create multiple Mutex
>   objects that represent the same named
>   system mutex, and you can use the
>   OpenExisting method to open an
>   existing named system mutex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use semaphores or named pipes (available in .Net 4.0) to do this.

Comment: I there a way to listen to the same named pipe form multiple WCF hosts? (It throws an addressalreadyinuseexception)